# R Version in screen different than expected

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, macintosh, r

Invoking R in a new terminal session loads R version 4.0.0, but if I go into a screen and invoke R, version 3.4.3 is loaded. How can I set the version of R invoked in screen to always be the version invoked out of a screen?

If I execute `type -a R` outside and inside the screen I get the following:

Outside the screen:

```
kf@karl Dropbox % type -a R
R is /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/R
R is /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/R
R is /usr/local/bin/R
```

Inside the screen:

```
kf@karl Dropbox % type -a R
R is /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/R
R is /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/R
R is /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/R
R is /usr/local/bin/R
```

It appears I need to tell screen to use the `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/R` path first.

This happens on my Mac OS Catalina v10.15.4

Thanks all.

Comment: please provide `type -a R` output in both situations (in screen and without screen).

Comment: Thanks for the comment binarysta. Added the info to the post. It appears I need to set the path for R while I'm in a screen environment.

Comment: you can manually set it always, but this should not happen normally, what is `echo $PATH` in both situations?

Comment: Please check `~./bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.screenrc`, somewhere `$PATH` is being prepended with `anaconda3/bin` so thats why it is duplicated in screen and this version of `R` being executed. you can share the output of `grep 'PATH' ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.screenrc`

Answer (score 1):

Your $PATH, if you set it to something different from the default PATH, should be set in .bash_profile or .bash_login (if you're using bash which it seems like you are).  Not in .bashrc and certainly not in .screenrc and certainly not in /etc/screenrc.  You generally want to set this once at login and it gets inherited in sub-shells and processes you start of which screen is one.  I have a feeling your problem lies here in where you are setting PATH more than once or in some other file than you are expecting.

To get a good feeling for where your $PATH is being set, you might try putting some echo statements in your various .bash*/.profile files.  `grep -i path .??*` will help you find where you are setting $PATH.

Order of how these files are read: [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)